# wxMaxima: Check whether a matrix is zeromatrix or not

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

Do we have a predefined function to check whether a matrix is a zero matrix or not? Else, how can this check be performed efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

`zeromatrixp (M)` from the maxima manual is what I was looking for!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).